# How to update APEX_ITEM.TEXT in table

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am creating one interactive report in that, i have a column of remarks which is an apex text item..

```
Now i want to update the text item values in table for remarks column.

 - Here is my interactive report query:

select CUST_ID,
       CHEQUE_AMOUNT,
       (APEX_ITEM.TEXT(REMARKS))       
from PDC_STATUS_HISTORY 
where STATUS in ('Pending') 
      AND APPROVER_BY=NVL(SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'), USER); 

Now i need to update the remarks column into table
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do that manually, but involves a lot of coding.

Instead of going into that direction, my advices is to (if possible for you) 'upgrade' the Interactive Report into an Interactive Grid. It looks the same and therefore your users will recognise it and feel comfortable, but now you will be able to edit (certain) values as well. That way, most of the coding comes out-of-the-box by APEX.

**Interactive Grid:**

- Add a new page using the wizard
- Choose Interactive Grid as the page/region type
- Enter following query as the source

```sql
select CUST_ID,
       CHEQUE_AMOUNT,
       REMARKS       
from   PDC_STATUS_HISTORY
where  STATUS in ('Pending') 
AND    APPROVER_BY = NVL( SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'), USER);
```

- Specify CUST_ID as the primary key and read-only
- Specify CHEQUE_AMOUNT as read-only

Hope this answer is useful to you! Let me know.

Comment: User only asked for Intractive report, before to that we have used IG only..
Thanks for your reply and if you could help for my issue please revert

Comment: If you add the new page as IG and then disable editing on cust_id and cheque_amount, you have the same results as with IR now, but then remarks will be editable. Sounds to me like the solution you want to achieve. If this is not the case, please try to explain why IG is not an option..